# What did Schopenhauer mean by 'slipping a tip to a head-waiter when pretending to be above such things'?

Tags: ethics, schopenhauer

I bolded and italicised this simile below.

<sub>Source: p. 46 Middle. *Ethics: A Beginner's Guide* (2015) by Peter Cave.</sub>

> **Slipping a tip:** Kant thought moral duty must be carried out for its own sake; 
>   yet happiness, as the highest good, is deserved by those morally strong 
>   enough to perform their duties. Happiness depends on God's salvific will, on 
>   his grace. Schopenhauer quipped, '***That is akin to slipping a tip to a head- 
>   waiter when pretending to be above such things*.**'

<sub>Source: [pp. 40 Bottom-41 Top.](https://books.google.com/books?id=BwRoA_oe4bwC&lpg=PA41&ots=YBh5aQBN3T&dq=%22slipping%20a%20tip%20to%20a%20head-waiter%22&pg=PA41#v=onepage&q=%22slipping%20a%20tip%20to%20a%20head-waiter%22&f=false) *The Sense of the Past: Essays in the History of Philosophy*
by Bernard Williams.</sub>

> [p. 40 Bottom]
>           
>      For Plato, as also for Aristotle, it was a trivial truth that if it is rational 
>   for one to pursue a certain course of life or to be a certain sort of person, 
>   then those things must make for a satisfactory state of oneself called 
>   *eudaimonia*—a term which can only be translated as 'happiness'. But not 
>   everyone now will regard it as a triviality, or even as true, that it is only 
>   rational to do what in the end makes for one's own happiness. More- 
>   over, many people who do agree that that is true will not in fact be 
>   agreeing with the same thing as Plato and Aristotle meant. These facts 
>   are due not only to imperfections of that translation, but also to changes 
>   in views of life—changes which themselves have no doubt affected our 
>   understanding of the term 'happiness'. A proper charting of the complex 
>   relations of these words would involve a whole history of Western ethi- 
>   cal thought. What is certain is that *eudaimonia* did not necessarily imply 
>   the maximization of pleasure; and when Plato, supposedly having shown 
>   in the *Republic* that justice is the proper state of the soul, goes on to ar
>   gue that the life of the just man is also a large number of times more
>
> [p. 41 Top]
>
> pleasant than that Of the unjust, this is meant to be an entirely additional 
>   consideration. It is in this respect much like Kant's assurance that virtue 
>   will be rewarded in an after-life, coming as that does after his insistence 
>   that it must be regarded as its own reward (a manoeuvre which Schopenhauer disobligingly compared to ***slipping a tip to a head-waiter who pre- 
>   tends to be above such things***). The state of *eudaimonia* should be inter- 
>   preted as that of living as a man best could, and when one finds some 
>   Greek thinkers suggesting that one can attain *eudaimonia* although one 
>   is the victim Of torture, the linguistic strain that is undoubtedly set up ex- 
>   presses not just a semantic difficulty, but, under that, the substantial dif- 
>   ficulty of supposing that being tortured is compatible with living as one 
>   best could.

Comment: Schipenhauer critique to the seemingly incosistency in Kant's theory amounts to : Kant first he asserts that to perform our own duties is a reward in itself, and later add that well-doing will be reward in the after-life, going back to a "reward" theory of virtue. The quip is : "the head-waiter does not care for tips (due to his "high status") but at the same time he covertly cash them."